# Can't see Azure Internal Load Balancer on Azure Load Balancer Panel

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer, vnet

I am working on existing project which is created by different developer/vendor. Per documentation, Azure Internal Load Balancer is configured for Azure Cloud Service (Protocol Gateway Instance). However I can not see any Load Balancer with that name under Azure Load Balancer panel. If I look at the .cscfg file of Cloud Service, I can see Load Balancer Configuration as well, as below.

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
    <!--VNet and subnet must be classic virtual network resources, not Azure Resource Manager resources.-->
    <VirtualNetworkSite name="Group resource-group-name vnet-name" />
    <AddressAssignments>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="cloud-service-instance-name">
        <Subnets>
          <Subnet name="subnet-name" />
        </Subnets>
      </InstanceAddress>
    </AddressAssignments>
    <!--VNet settings-->
    <LoadBalancers>
      <LoadBalancer name="load-balancer-name">
        <FrontendIPConfiguration type="private" subnet="subnet-name" staticVirtualNetworkIPAddress="cloud-service-instance-private-vnet-ip" />
      </LoadBalancer>
    </LoadBalancers>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

Can anyone help me to understand this configuration? Cloud Service is in a production environment and working perfectly fine.

Is there any different Internal Load Balancer configuration for Classic VNet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Azure cloud service is used for classic deployment models and Azure load balancer is used for Azure Resource Manager deployment models, you could not see it via Azure load balancer panel.

Make sure you understand  [deployment models and tools - Azure Resource Manager vs. classic deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model) You can also Learn how to create an [Internet facing load balancer using Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-create-basic-load-balancer-powershell).

> The Resource Manager and classic deployment models represent two
>   different ways of deploying and managing your Azure solutions. You
>   work with them through two different API sets, and the deployed
>   resources can contain important differences. The two models are not
>   compatible with each other. This article describes those differences.
>
> To simplify the deployment and management of resources, Microsoft
>   recommends that you use Resource Manager for all new resources. If
>   possible, Microsoft recommends that you redeploy existing resources
>   through Resource Manager.